# NVIDIA Driver doesn't recognize the main laptop screen, but good with external displays, Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.15.0.76-generic, GPU is Geforce GTX 960 (GM107 chip). I set up Nvidia drivers 440.33.01 with Cuda 10.2 last week, and everything was working perfectly. I believe the issue started after a minor update to either ubuntu (or something else) today. Currently, booting happens on the main laptop screen, but as soon as I login using gdm3, the main laptop screen turns black. (Still can be used for TTY though) Nvidia-smi and related commands work fine. 
I purged and reinstalled nvidia drivers and cuda, and without drivers the main laptop screen works fine. (But in this case the external display is not recognized)

```
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:134 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:132 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Output of nvidia-smi

```
Wed Feb 12 21:41:22 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 960M    On   | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    205MiB /  4043MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1415      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            14MiB |
|    0      1534      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          11MiB |
|    0      1932      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            89MiB |
|    0      2180      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          81MiB |
|    0      2714      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       1MiB |
```

I don't think I have an hardware issue. Might be related to X, maybe manually editing Xconf may help, but running nvidia-xconfig did not solve the issue.
I will be very grateful if anyone can help, thanks.

Comment: You might need [bumblebee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bumblebee) for Intel HD Graphics 530. These dual-chipsets _are_ a hardware issue.

Comment: Not a real solution but manually edited the xorg.conf file to at least get the screen working when external monitor is attached/detached. https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1071417/linux/nvidia-driver-440-33-doesn-t-recognize-the-main-laptop-screen-but-good-with-external-displays-ubun-/?offset=4#5431771